# Is there a way to get content list of a zip file on Google Drive without downloading it?

Tags: python-3.x, google-api-client

We have a shared drive that users will upload zip files into. Is there a way to directly get the file name and last modified date of the Zip file contents without downloading the file?

Currently, for each file, we download the zip file, extract, get each file name and last modified date, then save it to a table. While it is working, it is extremely slow.

I am hoping for a more efficient way to deal with this.

Comment: Can I ask you about the sizes of zip files you want to use?

Comment: @Tanaike, it ranges from 60kb to 70mb. Huge range, I know. They all contains some form of text file (csv, tab-delimited, etc). I just need the file name and modified dates.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that if the maximum size is less than 50 MB, it can use Web Apps with Google Apps Script as an API. But from your replying, unfortunately, 70 MB cannot be used for Google Apps Script because of the limitation of the blob. I apologize I couldn't help you.

Comment: Thanks for trying! I figure there should be a better way out there. I will keep searching and reply to this thread if I find an answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize I couldn't directly resolve your issue.

Comment: Were you able to solve this @Colin Lee ? I am facing the same issue right now.